# Como inserir diversos dados recebidos de um mesmo campo?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um formulário em html que possui um campo onde o usuário vai inserindo os dados como mostra o código abaixo, esse formulário é dinâmico e o usuário pode inserir quantas informações quiser, no caso a seguir eu coloquei apenas seis sistemas.

A minha dúvida é: Como eu vou receber essa quantidade de informações no PHP pelo $_POST e inserir no banco? A query eu até sei fazer, mas eu sei q tenho que trabalhar com uma estrutura de repetição, mas como?

Código HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="tags">
<li class="addedTag">
sistema1
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema1" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="addedTag">
sistema2
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema2" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="addedTag">
sistema3
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema3" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="addedTag">
sistema4
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema4" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="addedTag">
sistema5
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema5" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="addedTag">
sistema6
<span class="tagRemove" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</span>
<input type="hidden" value="sistema6" name="tags[]"/>
</li>
<li class="tagAdd taglist">
<input type="text" id="search-field"/>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

    $tags = $_POST['tags']; 
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, ""INSERT INTO tb_conhecimentos .......
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse [`form`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) vai retornar algo assim:

***Código:***

```
<?php

    var_dump($_POST['tags']);
```

***Saída:***

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "sistema1" 
           [1]=> string(8) "sistema2" 
           [2]=> string(8) "sistema3" 
           [3]=> string(8) "sistema4" 
           [4]=> string(8) "sistema5" 
           [5]=> string(8) "sistema6" }
```

---

**Como faz para gravar esses itens?**

*Com um* [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
<?php

    foreach($_POST['tags'] as $value):
        echo $value;
    endforeach;
```

o `$value` seria cada item enviado dentro desse `array` de `tags`.

---

Se a versão do [***PHP***](http://php.net/) for ***`>= 5.2.0`*** pode usar [***filter_input***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php):

```
<?php

    $tags = filter_input (INPUT_POST, "tags", FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    foreach($tags as $value):
        echo $value;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Os dados são escritos mas notei que se eu usar o FOREACH eu não consigo inserir os dados diretamente no banco né... pq da erro de php "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in" ... usando "$query = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tb_tag (tag_id, tag_conhecimento_id, tag_nome) VALUES (NULL, '$query','$tags');");"

Comment: Se está fazendo errado dentro do `foreach` pega a variavel $value e insere em `tag_nome`! do jeito que você está errado mesmo.

Comment: o rapaz. e verdade... vacilo meu! mas mesmo assim cotninua dando a mensagem `"Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\base\incluir_validacao.php on line 113"` .... agora o codigo ficou assim: `$query_insert = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tb_tag (tag_id, tag_conhecimento_id, tag_nome) VALUES (NULL, '$query','$value');");`

Comment: o que tem dentro da `$query`? pode ser assim se o tag_id for auto_incremento `mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tb_tag (tag_conhecimento_id, tag_nome) VALUES ('$query','$value');");`

Comment: rapaz... você matou a xarada! tirei o $query e usei só o $value e ele inseriu... mas o que $query traz é o último valor que foi inserido em outra tabela!

Comment: então, é alguma coisa no seu cadastro que está faltando !!!

Comment: Verdade... vou fuçar aqui! Obrigado pela ajuda!!!